# Turn Words Inside an EditText Into a Contact Icon

Tags: android, android-edittext, custom-view

I'm not quite sure what to even call this. Rather than plain text editing I'd like to implement the same system here, so when a user types in other users' names followed by a space the name is replaced with a view like below. What are the basic steps to get this effect?[image: GMail address icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called chips.

Here are some libraries that might do the trick:
https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips
https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't research anything without the name